# Ошибка в SQL запросе | sqlite3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql, база-данных, sqlite3

Почему в этом коде я получаю ошибку `no such column: test2`? Вроде бы запрос составлен корректно...

```
import sqlite3


db = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
cur = db.cursor()

cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS abc(test1 TEXT, test2 TEXT, test3 TEXT)")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO abc VALUES (test2)",('aaaaaa'))

db.commit()
db.close()
```

Ошибка полностью:

```
File "d:\programm\BotParsSale\test.py", line 11, in <module>
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO abc VALUES (test2)",('aaaaaa'))
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: test2
```

Comment: То test1, то test2.. Вы уж определитесь с тем, какое поле указано в сообщении об ошибке, что ли...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
cur = db.cursor()

cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS abc(test1 TEXT, test2 TEXT, test3 TEXT)")

cur.execute("INSERT INTO abc(test2) VALUES (?) ", ('aaaaaa',))
db.commit()

res = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM abc").fetchall()

print(res[0])
db.close()

(None, 'aaaaaa', None)
```

Comment: Дополните, пожалуйста, ответ текстовым описанием, то именно было неправильно и как вы это исправили.

Comment: Самая большая ошибка, что при создании базы не назначен уникальный идентификатор, а ошибка синтаксиса просто не туда написал имя поля, и не правильно выбрал тип заполнителя, нужно было выбрать какой-нибудь тип iterable, здесь например кортеж.